# How can Qt containers be passed as parameters to functions of a shared library?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, abi

I am writing a library function, and I really need to be able to pass arguments like `vectors` & `maps` to it.

I know you can't have a function with STL parameters declared at the header of a library

```
std::map<int> FixMap( const std::map<int> & );
```

because of binary compatibility issues, unless the library and executable were compiled with the same compiler & settings.

One the other hand, using the *Qt Template Library* the following works

```
QMap<int> FixMap( const QMap<int> & );
```

even though the DLL they provide has probably been compiled by a different compiler than mine.

What technique does **Qt** use with their `QMap`, `QValueList`,`QString`, to overcome this compatibility issue ?

I've read their code a bit, but I can't isolate the technique.

**Question 1:** Can someone explain to me (via a short walk-through perhaps?) on how to write code that applies their technique?

The only technique I know that works is providing the `string`/`map` as an *opaque pointer*, or using the *pImpl* idiom.

**Question 2:** can I use STLPort instead of the 'native' STL headers to achieve this kind of calls? How does that affect the performance of STL?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is actually referring to a precompiled binary? In general, template code is always compiled afresh each time it's used. (You cannot "compile" templates.)

Comment: Even with the "qt technique" you can run into problems easily when compiling things with differnt compilers/settings. It just saves you from a few occasions where you can replace the shared library without having to recompile the programs that use it

Answer (score 0):

The first example is just as okay as the second, even if the library was built using another compiler than what you are using. What is important is that the [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), or ABI for short, is the same for both your program and the library.

Qt doesn't use anything special when they build their libraries.

Comment: Then what is really the problem when I export a function like  `std::map<int> FixMap( const std::map<int> & );` from my library? I am referring to the question 'calling functions with STL parameters from a shared library'

Comment: @GrimFandango Can't tell unless you provide us with an error.

Comment: The problem that the first example has been described in detail in item 63 of book **C++ Coding Standards** by **Sutter** and **Alexandrescu**.